# Rails scope for null return incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I want to find records where `work_end_at IS NULL`.

The type of `work_end_at` is `datetime`.
And, I try this `WorkingHistory.where("work_end_at IS NULL")`.

I got an empty result. However, record with id 532 is the one that I want to find.

ruby version: 2.1.5

rails version: 4.0.4

[rails console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oj1B.png)

```
WorkingHistory.where("work_end_at IS NULL")
SELECT `working_histories`.* FROM `working_histories` WHERE (work_end_at IS NULL)
[]
```

edit:

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saI2T.png)

```
# console result
WorkingHistory.where(work_end_at: [nil, ""])
SELECT `working_histories`.* FROM `working_histories` WHERE ((`working_histories`.`work_end_at` = '' OR `working_histories`.`work_end_at` IS NULL))
[]

WorkingHistory.where(work_end_at: nil)
SELECT `working_histories`.* FROM `working_histories` WHERE `working_histories`.`work_end_at` IS NULL
[]

#WorkingHistory.find(532)
SELECT `working_histories`.* FROM `working_histories` WHERE `working_histories`.`id` = 532 LIMIT 1
#<WorkingHistory:0x0055d8737a8838> {
                       :id => 532,
                  :user_id => 63,
              :contract_id => 220,
            :work_start_at => Thu, 05 Jul 2018 13:54:28 CST +08:00,
               :created_at => Thu, 05 Jul 2018 13:54:33 CST +08:00,
               :updated_at => Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:13:21 CST +08:00,
              :work_end_at => nil,
            :work_time_sec => 3721,
    :contract_milestone_id => 822
}

# WorkingHistory model
class WorkingHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contract
  belongs_to :contract_milestone

  has_one :memo
  has_many :snapshots
  has_many :details, class_name: 'WorkingHistoryDetail'

  scope :custom_region, -> (date) { where(work_start_at: date) }
  scope :custom_day, -> (date) { where(work_start_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day) }
  scope :custom_week, -> (date) { where(work_start_at: date.beginning_of_week..date.end_of_week) }
  scope :custom_month, -> (date) { where(work_start_at: date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month) }
  scope :custom_year, -> (date) { where(work_start_at: date.beginning_of_year..date.end_of_year) }
  scope :relate, -> (datetime) { where('work_start_at < ? && work_end_at >= ?', datetime, datetime) }
  scope :current, -> { where('work_start_at < ? && work_end_at = ?', Time.zone.now, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') }
  scope :cross_cycle_working, -> { where('dayofweek(work_start_at) = ? AND dayofweek(work_end_at) = ?', 6, 1) }
  scope :not_end_or_end_at_today, -> { where('work_end_at >= ?', Time.zone.today.beginning_of_day) }
  scope :without_end_at, -> { where("work_end_at IS NULL or work_end_at = ''") }

  before_save :assign_to_contract_milestone

  def end_working?
    self.work_end_at.present?
  end

  def update_work_time_sec
    return unless self.end_working?

    limit_hours = contract.limit_hours * 3600
    total_working_time = contract_milestone.working_histories.where("working_histories.id != ?", self.id).sum(:work_time_sec)
    details_sum = self.details.summation
    if (details_sum + total_working_time) > limit_hours
      difference = (limit_hours - total_working_time) > 0 ? (limit_hours - total_working_time) : 0
      self.update!(work_time_sec: difference)
    else
      secs = details_sum > 0 ? details_sum : 0
      self.update!(work_time_sec: secs)
    end
  end

  private

  def work_end_and_yet_assign?
    work_time_sec.present? && contract_milestone_id.blank?
  end
end


# db schema

  create_table "working_histories", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "contract_id"
    t.datetime "work_start_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "work_end_at"
    t.integer  "work_time_sec",         default: 0,     null: false
    t.integer  "contract_milestone_id"
    t.boolean  "finish",                default: false
  end
```

edit:

```
#The result of querying the data directly with MySQL

mysql> SELECT * FROM working_histories where `working_histories`.`id` = 532;
+-----+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------+
| id  | user_id | contract_id | work_start_at       | created_at          | updated_at          | work_end_at         | work_time_sec | contract_milestone_id | finish |
+-----+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------+
| 532 |      63 |         220 | 2018-07-05 05:54:28 | 2018-07-05 05:54:33 | 2018-08-16 03:13:21 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |          3721 |                   822 |      1 |
+-----+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Always paste the content of the output rather than an image

Comment: Can you add the output of `WorkingHistory.find(532)`?

Comment: Can you query for this object directly in DB to see its values directly, without Rails? And which database are you using?

Comment: @TyroneWilson I added the output of the query.

Comment: @mefe I can't directly access DB. The DB is AWS RDS MySQL.

Comment: @william you should be able to connect to that db - check this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html
Or you can use `rails db` command to connect to mysql shell directly.

Comment: This is a very strange bug indeed. I can see you should be getting the correct result. What is the result of querying the data directly with MySQL. I think this could be a MySQL issue not a rails one. I agree with @mefe

Comment: @mefe Thanks, I understand how to connect to db now. The value about work_end_at is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: I found that work_end_at of the new record is `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead of `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not resolved after upgrading the MySQL version.

I found that the default value of `work_end_at` in MySQL schema is `0000-00-0000:00 00:00`. It is different from `db/schema.rb`.

I think that's why I can't get the correct results.

```
mysql> describe working_histories;
+-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| user_id               | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| contract_id           | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| work_start_at         | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at            | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| updated_at            | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| work_end_at           | datetime   | YES  |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| work_time_sec         | int(11)    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| contract_milestone_id | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| finish                | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0                   |                |
+-----------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WorkingHistory.where(work_end_at: [nil, ""])
```

It'll find both that have null or empty value, if you only want null you can remove '' and use

```
WorkingHistory.where(work_end_at: nil)
```

**EDIT 1**

This is the output when I tried with your application, works fine for me

[image]

Comment: Both of his solutions should work. What does the query look like in the console?

Comment: can you show the output when you tried the query above ?

Comment: @Subash I have pasted the output of the above query

Comment: @william that is very weird, can you post your workinghistory model

Comment: @william  don't see any reason why its not working? is it possible for you to upload your app to a git repo with your db dump so I can check that out ?

Comment: @Subash sorry, I can't share the git repo, because the repository is private.  I can post db schema about workinghistory.

Comment: ok, upload the schema, I am not talking about sharing the current repo, if you can create a public sample repo where you can reproduce the current behaviour, it would help me debug it

Comment: @Subash I created a new project with same schema and models. And, I use local MySQL. However, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @william can you push your this new project to github ?

Comment: @Subash [scope_problem](https://github.com/WilliamLINWEN/scope_problem)

Comment: @william works fine for me, can you specify the mysql versions, ruby mysql gem version and if there is anything extra that you are doing ?

Comment: @Subash MySQL version is `5.6.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`. `mysql2` gem version is `0.3.19`.  I will try to upgrade MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, you have a little issue with MySQL database. In this database, 'empty' DateTime field has a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` instead of `null`. However, Rails shows (or 'casts') it as `nil`, so that might be misleading.

First solution would be to query for that value treating it same as a `nil` or `''`.

Second solution would be to update MySQL/Rails version, as @Subash tried to reproduce your problem and couldn't do it, so probably there are some differences between versions there.

Comment: I try this `WorkingHistory.where(work_end_at: '0000-00-00 00:00:00')`.  And, I got the right output ! Maybe there are some differences between the versions. I will try to upgrade MySQL version.

Comment: @william any updates? Did you upgrade MySQL? Did it help?

Comment: Sorry, I got some internal problem. I can't upgrade MySQL myself. If I can upgrade MySQL version, I will update it.